# How to export a dependecy or jar package at runtime?

Tags: apache, maven, jar, eclipse-plugin

I want to export a package from an embedded jar from my plugin. Like, MyProject/folder/myJarName.jar packages from my current plugin. For this I tried using apache felix and exported package, specified the location of the jar in bundle classpath. But, when I build my project, it manifest file complains that, package 'com.demoName.package' doesn't exist in this plugin. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To export your project jar packages to the external plugins, need to do the following.

1. Add your jar file in the plugin.xml **classpath** section, that you can
   find in the **Runtime** tab - This will make your jar available at run-time.
2. And in the **Exported packages** section, add the required packages
   which you wanted to export- so that, other plugins can also access these packages.

Please find the below screenshot. I've added httclient.jar in my project lib folder and made it available to the run-time through Classpath.
[image]